# Ugly ::selection two-color background

Tags: google-chrome, css, selection

I'm trying to use a custom `::selection` effect in Chrome but getting this bad blue coloration on highlighted text:

[image]

Here's my CSS:

```
::selection {
    color:#ffffff; 
    background: #000000;
}
::-moz-selection {
    color:#ffffff; 
    background: #000000;
}
::-webkit-selection {
    color:#ffffff;
    background: #000000;
}
```

I can't replicate the error in Firefox - is there anything I can do, or is it just a feature of the browser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to wrap the text in a `<p>` tag.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a little confused, because the selected text is applying the style from the code you're using... white text on a black background.

Is the light blue part the problem? If that's the case, I think the structure/css of the surrounding container(s) would be more helpful to get to the bottom of this.

Comment: Sorry - the light blue is the problem. I just realized I can fix it by wrapping the text in `<p>` tags.